# ClipDrawable how to change the image

Tags: android, android-drawable

Im trying to implement a ClipDrawable appear by clicking with diferents images

I have this working with a simple image

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    drawable = (ClipDrawable) imageview.getDrawable();
    drawable.setLevel(0);
    imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawable.setLevel(drawable.getLevel()+1000);
        }
    });
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/clip_source"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

clip_source.xml

```
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tree"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
 />
```

this is working but for my project I need to change the image displayed with a variable to display diferents images depending of the user input

Answer (score 0):

I only find one way, using diferent files for each ClipDraw

MainActivity.java

```
if(aa == false){
    t = (ClipDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clip1);
}else{
    t = (ClipDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clip2);
}

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(back);
imageview.setImageDrawable(t);
t.setLevel(0);
imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        t.setLevel(t.getLevel()+1000);
    }
});
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

clip1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/farm"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
 />
```

clip2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/werehouse"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
 />
```

this solve my problem but have the disadvantage of need one file for each image, and I will need at least 20